# Permutations of GAUSS

Tags: combinatorics

Find the number of permutation of the word: GAUSS

Using the definition: $\frac{n!}{(n-k)!}$

Where here are $n = 5$ but I am not sure how to choose $k$?

Can somebody help me with the actual definition of a permutation in this context?

Thanks@

Comment: $$\frac{5!}{2!}$$ as there are $5$ letters and $2$ repetitions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably know there are

$$5!=120$$

permutations of a five-letter word if all letters are different.

But wait, the letter "S" occurs twice! So you've just counted twice as many permutations as there really are, because you cannot distinguish between configurations where the two letters "S" are permuted (i.e. swapped).

This gives

$$\frac{5!}{2!}=60$$

permutations in total for the word "GAUSS".

Answer (score 1):

One more way: you have 5 slots and 4 classes, 3 of size 1 and 1 of size 2. For the last one, you need to select 2 slots out of 5: $\binom{5}{2}$. Obviously for each selection you have 3 slots for any other class. Hence the solution is 
$$
N = \binom{5}{2} 3! = \frac{5!}{2!}
$$